# Kubernetes Node Conformance Test

Tags: docker, kubernetes

So I am trying to run node conformance test for kubernetes.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/node-conformance/
Heres the thing , its complaining about unsupported docker version.
After a look into the go code it requires a 1.7.x version of docker however I cant pull that version down as its unsupported , anyone solved this problem? 
here is my output:

```
~# docker run -it --privileged --net=host   -v /:/rootfs -v $CONFIG_DIR:$CONFIG_DIR -v $LOG_DIR:/var/result   k8s.gcr.io/node-test:0.2
Running Suite: E2eNode Suite
============================
Random Seed: 1547126906 - Will randomize all specs
Will run 88 of 162 specs

Running in parallel across 8 nodes

OS: Linux
KERNEL_VERSION: 4.15.0-43-generic
CONFIG_NAMESPACES: enabled
CONFIG_NET_NS: enabled
CONFIG_PID_NS: enabled
CONFIG_IPC_NS: enabled
CONFIG_UTS_NS: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUPS: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED: enabled
CONFIG_CPUSETS: enabled
CONFIG_MEMCG: enabled
CONFIG_INET: enabled
CONFIG_EXT4_FS: enabled
CONFIG_PROC_FS: enabled
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_REDIRECT: enabled (as module)
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_COMMENT: enabled (as module)
CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS: enabled (as module)
CONFIG_AUFS_FS: enabled (as module)
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_DM: enabled
CGROUPS_CPU: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUACCT: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUSET: enabled
CGROUPS_DEVICES: enabled
CGROUPS_FREEZER: enabled
CGROUPS_MEMORY: enabled
DOCKER_VERSION: 18.06.0-ce
F0110 13:28:26.746125     129 e2e_node_suite_test.go:96] system validation failed: unsupported docker version: 18.06.0-ce
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of thing I can suggest you to run Conformance Test:

1) Forget about https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/node-conformance/

2) Install [kubetest](https://github.com/kubernetes/test-infra/tree/master/kubetest) and follow [Conformance Testing in Kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/conformance-tests.md) instruction

3) Use [sonobuoy](https://github.com/heptio/sonobuoy) solution from Heptio. More information you can find here: [Conformance Testing - 1.11+](https://github.com/heptio/sonobuoy/blob/master/docs/conformance-testing.md)

Good Luck!